# How to build Guzzle GET request for -d data in curl

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-5, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to access an API using Guzzle in Laravel 5.5.

The command in `curl` looks like:

```
curl http://apiurl.com/getRequest -d "api_key=token_value"
```

Now using Guzzle, I started to code as below:

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://apiurl.com/']);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'getRequest', [
             'headers' => [
                           'api_key' => ['token_value']
                         ]
]);
var_dump($response->getStatusCode());
var_dump(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
```

Now I am able to see `statusCode` as `200` and `getBody` as `Null`. But when I use the same request using `curl` then I am able to see the complete data.

Could someone resolve it please?

Answer (score 0):

When comparing differences between `curl` and `Guzzle`, I highly recommend using [`-v`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) (`curl`) and the [`debug`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug) request option (`Guzzle`).  The verbose output allows for visual comparison of the requests that each software is transmitting.

The `curl` man page indicates that [`-d`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) and [`--data`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) send POST requests.

> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

A pair of changes are required in order to send the desired request with `Guzzle`:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
    'form_params' => [
        'api_key' => $key_value,
    ],
]);
```

The first change is the type of request that is being sent (GET => POST).  The second, is the usage of `form_params`.  The [`form_params`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params) request option is used to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST requests.